# How to add custom styled to a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, styled-components, css-in-js

I have a styled component `<Icon type="loader"/>`. I would like to create another styled component by adding some custom style to this Icon component. I need to pass `type` to the Icon component how can I achieve this?

`` const loader = styled(Icon)` font-size:'inherit'` ``

Directly passing the Icon without any prop works fine.

I have tried this:
`const CustomIcon = () => <Icon type="loader"/>`

`` const loader = styled(CustomIcon)` font-size:'inherit'` ``

this gives error.

Comment: That first way (`const loader = styled(Icon)\` font-size:'inherit'\``) seems like it should work, though it should be `const Loader = styled(Icon)\` font-size:'inherit'\`` since you are returning a React component. What issue do you have with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first way would be sufficient.

```
const Loader = styled(Icon)`
  font-size: inherit;
`;
```

You can pass `type="loader"` to `Loader`:

```
<Loader type="loader" />
```

You can also specify the `type` prop when you define `Loader`:

```
const Loader = styled(Icon).attrs(() => ({
  type: 'loader',
}))`
  font-size: inherit;
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Loader /> // type="loader" passed to styled Icon
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-add-custom-styled-to-a-styled-component]

Demo code:

```
const Icon = styled(({ type, ...props }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "loader":
      return <div {...props} className={props.className + " loader"} />;

    default:
      return <div {...props} />;
  }
})`
  font-size: 3rem;

  &.loader {
    color: red;
  }
`;

const Loader = styled(Icon).attrs(() => ({
  type: "loader"
}))`
  font-size: initial; // overrides Icon fontsize
`;

...

<Icon>Test</Icon>
<Icon type="loader">Test</Icon>
<Loader>Test</Loader>
```

[image]